# How do you find lyrics with the parts labelled?

Tags: lyrics

https://devilmaycry.fandom.com/wiki/Bury_the_Light

Here, we see that the parts are labelled as Verse, Chorus or Bridge. Is there a website with a bunch of lyrics with the parts correctly labelled so I can become more proficient at writing lyrics?

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing you can figure out for yourself once you know what Verse, Chorus and Bridge mean?

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for something like [**Genius.com**](https://genius.com/), which provides song lyrics with labeled parts for each section of the song. This could include labels for **Verse [#], Pre-Chorus, Chorus, Intro, Outro** or **Bridge.**

For example, [their lyrical page for Mr. Brightside by The Killers](https://genius.com/The-killers-mr-brightside-lyrics) provides the following labels:

1. [Verse 1] *(Coming out of my cage and I've been doing just fine...)*
2. [Pre-Chorus] *(And I just can't look; it's killing me...)*
3. [Chorus] *(Jealousy, turning saints into the sea...)*
4. [Instrumental Bridge]
5. [Verse 2]
6. [Pre-Chorus]
7. [Chorus]
8. [Instrumental Bridge]
9. [Outro] *(I never... I never... I never...)*

Other websites for song lyrics include [**Lyrics.com**](https://www.lyrics.com/) and [**AZLyrics.com**](https://www.azlyrics.com/).